# Setting up a simple login page with reactjs and firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: http://www.automationfuel.com/firebase-facebook-login-react/

but, i think some parts are missing and i'm not able to figure out exactly what to change in order to get the demo running. This is what i have at the moment:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import reactfire from 'reactfire';

var config = {
 apiKey: "legitimate value",
 authDomain: "legitimate value",
 databaseURL: "legitimate value",
 storageBucket: "legitimate value",
 messagingSenderId: "legitimate value"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
this.state = {user: null};

loginWithFacebook() {
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    this.setState({user: result.user});
}.bind(this));
}

logOut() {
  firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
  this.setState({user: null});
}.bind(this));
}

const user = this.state.user;
render() {
  return(
  <div>
  <p>Hi, {user.displayName}!</p>
  <button onClick={this.loginWithFacebook.bind(this)}>Login with Facebook</button><button onClick={this.logOut.bind(this)}>Log Out</button>
</div>
)
};

ReactDOM.render(
 <h1>Hello world!</h1>,
 document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Any ideas on how to get this up and running..? My current errors are syntax issues around the `loginWithFacebook()`, `logOut()`, and `render()` functions. I tried putting the function keyword in front of these functions but then i was getting undefined errors whenever `this.setState` tried to execute.

After googling my way through all my issues i was able to get the demo to work. Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import reactfire from 'reactfire';

export class App extends React.Component {

 constructor(){
 super();

 this.state = {user: null, isLoggedIn: false};
 }

loginWithFacebook() {
      firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
        this.setState({user: result.user, isLoggedIn: true});
      }.bind(this));
    };

  logOut() {
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
      this.setState({user: null, isLoggedIn: false});
    }.bind(this));
  };

  render() {
    const currentState = this.state;
    return(
      <div>
        <p>Hi! {currentState.isLoggedIn ? currentState.user.displayName : ''}</p>
        <button onClick={this.loginWithFacebook.bind(this)}>Login with Facebook</button><button onClick={this.logOut.bind(this)}>Log Out</button>
      </div>
    )
  };
}

var config = {
  apiKey: "data",
  authDomain: "data",
  databaseURL: "data",
  storageBucket: "data",
  messagingSenderId: "data"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();


ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Your methods aren't in a component class!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your methods in a `class` and then you must render the `class` component. See example below:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      user: null
    }  
  }

  loginWithFacebook() {
     ...
  }

  logOut() {
    ...
  }

  render() {
    const user = this.state.user;

    return (
      ...
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

Comment: Thanks, i just googled my way to a working example. I'm completely new to React and the tutorial sucked. I'll post my updated code now so other people can see what i did.